# LeakSanitizer doesn't produce report after program exit

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

I'm compiling with Address Sanitizer, and I'm trying to get leak sanitizer reports, but it is only producing an Address Sanitizer report and not producing a LeakSanitizer report after program exit for some reason.

I'm compiling on Centos 7.9 with G++ 9.3.1, Cmake version 3.16.2.

I'm compiling with

> list(APPEND SAN_FLAGS "-fsanitize=address" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-g3")

to enable leak sanitizer (which should be enabled with address sanitizer on Linux according to the docs)

I set

```
Environment="ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path=/var/log/foo_asan.log:detect_leaks=1"
```

in the service file, then ran my program with systemd (also on Centos 7.9).   Stopping the program with systemctl creates a foo_asan. log file as expected, but the log file only has an AddressSanitizer report, but no LeakSanitizer report.     How do I get the Leaksanitizer report?

Answer (score 1):

> the log file only has an AddressSanitizer report, but no LeakSanitizer report.

By default, AddressSanitizer aborts on error. LeakSanitizer only runs on `exit`, and since your program doesn't `exit`, you get no leak report.

Here is an example program which has both a memory leak and a buffer overflow:

```
#include <malloc.h>

void *alloc(size_t sz) { return malloc(sz); }
void fn(char *p, int n) { p[n] = '\0'; }

int main()
{
  const int sz = 10;
  fn(alloc(sz), sz);

  return 0;
}
```

If I build it with `clang -g -fsanitize=address leaky.c -o leaky` and run it with `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1`, I only get the error report:

```
=================================================================
==1130841==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000001a at pc 0x5555a7f31f0f bp 0x7ffc86de9420 sp 0x7ffc86de9418
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60200000001a thread T0
    #0 0x5555a7f31f0e in fn /tmp/leaky.c:4:32
    #1 0x5555a7f31f4c in main /tmp/leaky.c:9:3
...
==1130841==ABORTING     <<<=== Note this.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696071/how-to-make-addresssanitizer-not-stop-after-one-error-and-other-issues) shows how to make the program *not* abort on errors. When I do that, I get both the AddressSanitizer and the LeakSanitizer reports:

```
clang -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address leaky.c -o leaky
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1:halt_on_error=0 ./leaky

=================================================================
==1131013==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000001a at pc 0x560f9d467f0f bp 0x7ffef258d2b0 sp 0x7ffef258d2a8
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60200000001a thread T0
    #0 0x560f9d467f0e in fn /tmp/leaky.c:4:32
    #1 0x560f9d467f5c in main /tmp/leaky.c:9:3
...
=================================================================
==1131013==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 10 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x560f9d42d14e in __interceptor_malloc (/tmp/leaky+0xa314e) (BuildId: d2d081353c37b4b7a8659b1ac39242cfe6259078)
    #1 0x560f9d467eb4 in alloc /tmp/leaky.c:3:33
    #2 0x560f9d467f4f in main /tmp/leaky.c:9:6
    #3 0x7fbf2cc29209 in __libc_start_call_main csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 10 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Comment: I just tried this, but unfortunately still did not get LeakSanitizer report

Comment: @ruisen By "this" do you mean the example program in this answer or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this as in the method.   I tried it in my environment with my program, but still didn't get result.  I'm compiling with g++ though, and not clang.